# Update extent in MultiPolygon postgis layer layer do not work

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3

Wen trying to automatically update extent, nothing happens and extent still covers whole planet.

```
Name
...
Source
dbname='postgres' host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' sslmode=disable key='"id"' srid=4326 type=MultiPolygon checkPrimaryKeyUnicity='1' table="public"."..." (geom) sql=
Storage
PostgreSQL database with PostGIS extension
Comment

Encoding
UTF-8
Geometry
Polygon (MultiPolygon)
CRS
EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic
Extent
-180.0000000000000000,-90.0000000000000000 : 180.0000000000000000,90.0000000000000000
```

Comment: does it work manually, e.g. in the *DB Manager* *Info* panel of the layer? are your geometries stored as `geography` type in PostGIS?

Comment: Yes, the type is geography. I'll have to search for the the DB manager panel and this option. Iteresting part is that when all `ctrl-a` objects are selected zoom to selected feature work corretly. I was trying to edit raw file and changed extent there, but it was reseted during the loading. **IS there any way to minimize extent of the layer?** Or the Update extent booton should do it

Comment: @ThingumaBob ^^

Comment: no. QGIS handles the `geography` type differently than the `geometry` type and will always use the full extent of the underlying geographical reference system. consider the `geography` type as not meant for cartographic visualizations, but for spheroidal calculations and megeographicasurements in PostGIS only; you may want to e.g. use a *View* with a cast to `geometry`, or a second dedicated column with a spatial index.

Comment: @ThingumaBob _
no. QGIS handles the geography type differently than the geometry type and will always use the full extent _ do you know why so stiupid decison was taken?
Anyway, i have to cast the column to the geometry to make it work, ridicouls. I was using geography to have correct distance calculation

Comment: I will report bug in the evening

Comment: Well, the `geography` type has been implemented as a convenient and standardized way to get both spheroidal algebra as well as the power of types and indexes in PG. QGIS is primarily a planar cartographic environment, with it's own suit of spheroidal measurement functionality; neither is the `geography` type meant for planar visualizations, nor is QGIS in need to work with it. if measurements are the only application for the `geography` type (and no index searches) I suggest to rather switch to `geometry` for storage and cast when needed

Comment: @ThingumaBob Yes, it is how it will be exposed in the final view.